# Police in Bucharest

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

I am confused about the following in ***Captain America: Civil War***:

> After the attack in Vienna, they find Bucky in Bucharest. But why was the German police there? Why wasn't it the Romanian police arresting them?

Comment: Why do you think it was the German police? I don't remember that ever being specified in the movie.

Comment: Their uniforms said "Polizei". They had the German Flag on their uniforms. And they brought the Captain to Berlin.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed, thanks.

Comment: The taskforce hunting the spoilery person was going to arrest that person, since they are located in Germany its likely that there are quite a number of German Police officers involved

Comment: I don't think they were regular German police but like "special forces" or some such. They said as much in the movie.

Comment: Of course they weren't regular police officers. But even special police forces don't operate outside of Germany.

Comment: @adryr That's what you're lead to believe ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very sure this was a mistake made during production. Regular German police will not operate outside Germany. On the other hand the Volkswagen Beetle Cap is driving in Berlin does not have a german license plate.

Comment: And I guess no Umweltplakette too :)

Answer (score 14):

The “German Special Forces” are probably GSG-9.  They are a division of the border police (that's the literal) name, which were founded after the PLO's terrorist attack at the 1972 Munich olympics.

They are special forces in the sense that their training includes urban fighting and military training, but they are police because the military is forbidden to operate within Germany.

They do operate outside the country - their first big mission was in Mogadishu, after all - but with the consent of the local government.

I guess it's simplest to assume that the were there with the permission of the Romanian government.

Answer (score -2):

Why would the Romanian government consent to allow German Special Forces to arrest Bucky, when the country had its own special forces units?  Or better yet, why not have U.N. forces arrest Bucky?  The bombing had occurred in Vienna, Austria; not Germany; and the U.N. played a major role in the creation of the Sokovia Accords.

I think this was a case of a blooper.  Every movie has its bloopers.  And this was one of the bloopers featured in "CIVIL WAR".

Comment: “why not have U.N. forces arrest Bucky?” I’d guess that, at least in the MCU, apprehending assassins is not what UN forces are trained for; whereas German special forces were better prepared for this mission, and close enough to deploy in the timescale. They did take Bucky back to what looks like a fairly high-tech prison in Berlin; maybe that’s run by the same organisation.